# How do I completely reset my network settings on Ubuntu Server 20.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

So I rebooted my System and now no over the Internet is working anymore. For example, I can't ping 8.8.8.8 and can't ping the Server directly by the IP. I searched everything, and I can't fix it. `ifconfig`, `sudo iptables -F`, `netplan`, doesn't work, and I can't install them, because I have no direct access to the Server and I can't download it over apt-get because the network doesn't work. The only thing I have is access to the terminal over my v-Server provider.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!